# Callback function for sharepoint default list item forms

Tags: list-form, popup

I have a list view where title column opens in a popup window(Allowed to open in popup using SharePoint settings-no javascript).

I want to execute one callback function after the dialog closes. i know you can have a callback for popups which you open using javascripts but is there any way to have a callback for default popups ?

Answer (score 0):

SP Modaldialog can be created with with "dialogReturnValueCallback" option like:

```
var options = {
    title: "Dialog Title",
    width: 300,
    height: 300,
    url: "/testpage.aspx",
    dialogReturnValueCallback: function(dialogResult, returnValue)
    {
        console.log('Dialog closed');
    }
};

SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog(options);
```

Comment: Modal dialog is de SharePoint default popup... I don't know a way to attach a callback on the popup that appears when you set the list to open in dialog. You could change the way "Title" is rendered with CSR and attach your own method for opening the dialog...

Answer (score 0):

You could get the dialog instance using:

```
var dlg = SP.UI.ModalDialog.get_childDialog();
```

The default callback function should be:

```
RefreshPage(a){CoreInvoke("_RefreshPage",a)}
```

Did a check here, and in my case the callback function was on the following property:

```
dlg.$d_0
```

So you could change that one, example:

```
var dlg = SP.UI.ModalDialog.get_childDialog();

    dlg.$d_0 = function(a) { 
     if(a === 0) {
       console.log("Clicked Cancel")
     } else {
       console.log("Clicked Save")
     } 

    }
```

Comment: doesnt work for display item form cancel?

Comment: Should work. You'll have to run the code after the modal has been opened. Check SP.UI.ModalDialog.get_childDialog() using the browser console when the dialog is open.

Comment: I am adding ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(NewItemDialog, "SP.js") in document.ready  where NewItemDialog is your code